# Creating and Downloading Asset bundle from local server in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please **don't recommend** me the **Unity3d official links** I have tried it and it is not comprehensive and not providing necessary details. I am new and going to make **AssetBundles** in Unity3d. What is tried so far is given below with the help of unity official [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildingAssetBundles5x.html).

```
/// <summary>
/// AssetBundles are exported from the editor using script code. (This is similar to the 4.x approach.)
/// The following script exports AssetBundles.
/// </summary>
public class AssetBundleCreate {

    [MenuItem("Assets/Build AssetBundles")]
    static void BuildAllAssetBundles() {
        Debug.Log("asset build");
        BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles("Assets/AssetBundles");
    }

    [MenuItem("Assets/Get AssetBundle Names")]
    static void GetNames() {
        var names = AssetDatabase.GetAllAssetBundleNames();
        foreach(var name in names){
            Debug.Log("AssetBundle name is : " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

but code didn't producing any asset bundle instead it have made.
*file and .abc extension files*.
What i am missing and also **Share proper guide about Creating and Downloading Asset bundle from local server/pc in Unity 5**

Answer (score 2):

you should look at the high level AssetBundleManager https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager

Answer (score 2):

The Assetbundle we are creating is **platform specific:**
To create AssetBundle just write a C# script and put it inside **Editor** folder:
**Assets > Editor** 
Here Im providing ex. of android specific platform:

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

public class ExportAssetBundles : Editor {
    [MenuItem("Assets/Build AssetBundle")]
    static void ExportResource()
    {
        string path = "Assets/AssetBundle/myAssetBundle.unity3d";
        Object[] selection = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(Object), SelectionMode.DeepAssets);
        BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle(Selection.activeObject, selection, path,
                                       BuildAssetBundleOptions.CollectDependencies
                                     | BuildAssetBundleOptions.CompleteAssets,BuildTarget.Android);
    }
}
```

after that you can place target.unity3d file **locally or on remote server**:
Remember on android platform we have to use WWW class provided below. 
[imp] now we can also include script in assetbundle :
just try out script below, you have to attache this script to empty game object in your scene in which you want to import AssetBundle:

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AssetBundleAugmenter : MonoBehaviour {

 public string AssetName;
 public int Version;
 
 private GameObject mBundleInstance = null;

 
 void Start() {  
  StartCoroutine(DownloadAndCache());

  }

 // Update is called once per frame
 IEnumerator DownloadAndCache() {

  while(!Caching.ready)
   yield return null;
  
  // example URL of file on PC filesystem (Windows)
  // string bundleURL = "file:///D:/Unity/AssetBundles/MyAssetBundle.unity3d";
  
  // example URL of file on Android device SD-card
  string bundleURL = "file:///mnt/sdcard/AndroidCube.unity3d";
  
  using (WWW www = WWW .LoadFromCacheOrDownload(bundleURL, Version)) {
   yield return www;
   
   if (www .error != null)
    throw new UnityException("WWW Download had an error: " + www .error);

   // Load and retrieve the AssetBundle
   AssetBundle bundle = www .assetBundle;

   // Load the assembly and get a type (class) from it
   var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("txt.bytes");
   var type = assembly.GetType("MyClassDerivedFromMonoBehaviour");

   // Instantiate a GameObject and add a component with the loaded class
   GameObject go = new GameObject();
   go.AddComponent(type);

   if (AssetName == "") {
    mBundleInstance = Instantiate (bundle.mainAsset) as GameObject;
   }
   else {
    mBundleInstance = Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset (AssetName)) as GameObject;
   }
  
 
   // Unload the AssetBundles compressed contents to conserve memory
   bundle.Unload(false);

  }
 }
 
}
```

If you are not intrested in Exporting script then just skip the below part from given script:

```html
// Load the assembly and get a type (class) from it
   var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("txt.bytes");
   var type = assembly.GetType("MyClassDerivedFromMonoBehaviour");

   // Instantiate a GameObject and add a component with the loaded class
   GameObject go = new GameObject();
   go.AddComponent(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

*After around 4 years I have to deal with asset bundles again, current answer are outdated and lots of changed has occurred after this, therefore I am answering it.* 
For making and managing asset bundle along with its dependencies, now a great tool available for making the asset bundle which is [**asset bundle browser**](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/asset-bundle-browser-93571) and at least you require  **2017.1** for it. It is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/AssetBundles-Browser). It is very simple and easy.

You can make asset bundle with your favorite compression method quickly. The great amount of documentation is available on official site [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Browser.html).

[image]